# why compressed kernel image is used in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have googled this question over the internet but couldn't find anything useful related to this question that "why compressed kernel image like bzImage or vmlinuz is used as initial kernel image",

Possible solutions which i could think of are:

Due to memory constraint?

But initially compressed kernel image is located at hard disk or some other storage media and during boot up time after second stage bootloader, kernel is first decompressed in main memory and then it is executed.

So, when at later stage kernel is to be decompressed in main memory then what is the need to compress it first. I mean if main memory could hold decompressed kernel image then what is the need for kernel compression?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Generally the processor can decompress faster than the I/O system can read.  By having less for the I/O system to read, you reduce the time needed for boot.

This assumption doesn't hold for all hardware combinations, of course.  But it frequently does.

An additional benefit for embedded systems is that the kernel image takes up less space on the non-volatile storage, which may allow using a smaller (and cheaper) flash chip.  Many of [these systems](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start) have ~ 32MB of system RAM and only ~ 4MB of flash.

Comment: You are right for embedded systems memory constraint is I guess the most valid answer, but for PC which have large storage devices does processor thing is the best answer?

Comment: @user2311046: Remember that on a PC, loading the kernel image has to be done by the bootloader using very generic featureless BIOS calls, which also means very slow performance.  No DMA, no scatter/gather I/O, no command queuing.  EFI makes that a bit better, but you still want to get a minimal kernel loaded ASAP and switch to native communications with the I/O controller.  Because image loading is so slow, the image transferred should be as small as possible, which is achieved via compression.

Comment: Some systems also boot over a network; you may wish to make a *recover kernel* very small to fit on a USB stick, long ago a floppy, or a CD.  Most importantly, the `.config` file means you do not **HAVE** to do this.  It is up to the person configuring the kernel and *Ben* has given the valid reasons. Paradoxically, you may not wish to do this in an embedded system with *execute in place* flash.

Comment: @artlessnoise: Fitting on a floppy is quite a challenge, but I've never seen USB or CD media that couldn't fit an uncompressed image.  Load time remains very important, of course.  For some reason I only see execute-in-place used for the bootloader; not sure if the Linux kernel needs to be in writable memory to support self-modifying code or what.

Comment: [XIP_KERNEL](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/Kconfig?id=refs/tags/v3.12-rc2#n2067) is supported on at least the **ARM**.  As most *code* section are marked `rx` only, those portions may map to NOR-flash, QuadSPI-flash, ROM, etc which support `XIP` and require no loading and lower RAM requirements.  For the *CD* or *USB*, the idea is not to consume much space for a rarely needed *rescue* image; you might dual-purpose the storage.

Comment: @artlessnoise: On PCs, you'll never notice the difference in free space left over by compressed vs uncompressed kernel.  It's all about performance.  Even XIP-vs-decompress-to-RAM is about performance -- most of those flash interfaces you mentioned are an order of magnitude (or maybe two) slower than RAM.